# Change of variables in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am somewhat confused about the notation so I want to use the function variable explicit as $y(x)$

Lets say the equation is:

$$x^4\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}+x^3\frac{dy(x)}{dx}+y(x)=0$$

I will substitute $x=\frac1t,\ dx=-\frac{1}{t^2}dt,\ dx^2=\frac{1}{t^4}dt^2$ and I get:

$$ \frac{d(dy(\frac1t))}{dt^2}-\frac1t\frac{dy(\frac1t)}{dt}+y(\frac1t)=0$$

Now, I know that I must somehow extract a $+\frac2t\frac{dy(\frac1t)}{dt}$ (Question 1: how) and eventually get:

$$ \frac{d(dy(t))}{dt^2}+\frac1t\frac{dy(t)}{dt}+y(t)=0$$

Where $y(\frac1t)$ has become $y(t)$ (Question 2: how) . I solve it to get $J_o(t)$ and substitute back to get  $J_o(\frac1x)$.

Comment: the second derivate $dx^2=\frac{2}{t^4}dt^2$

Comment: No it does't work like that, here's what you should try. 

$-t^2 \frac{d}{dt}\left(-t^2\frac{d(y(1/t))}{dt}\right)$ , gives perfect answer. @grdgfgr

Comment: @grdgfgr , shouldn't the last term $y\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$ be simply $y(t)$ as well?

Comment: @Mann Here is the problem. Using your notation I must have: $$\frac{d(y(\frac1t))}{dt}=y'(\frac1t)$$ but what I "want" to do is $$\frac{d(y(\frac1t))}{dt}=-\frac{1}{t^2}y'(\frac1t)$$ which clearly will not work

Comment: @grdgfgr , I wrote $y'(1/t)$ as $\frac{d(y(1/t)}{d(1/t)}$ Moreover if you clearly inspect your derivative you would see it as a product of $\dfrac{d(1/t)}{dt}* \dfrac{d(y(1/t))}{d(1/t)}$ Why would you want $\dfrac{d(y(1/t))}{d(1/t)}$ into your equation , it clearly ask only for $\frac{d(y(1/t)}{dt}$

Comment: If it just seems confusing then , @abel got a point, define your function $g(x)$ as $y(1/x)$ and not use as $y(x)$ as $y(1/x)$ as in my case, in the end it's just changing notation form y to g. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a function $g$ in terms of $y$ by $$g(1/x) = y(x), \quad g(x) = y(1/x).\tag 1$$

we will use the convention that all $y$'s are evaluated at $x$ and $g$'s at $1/x$. taking derivatives and using chain rule, we have
$$\begin{align}y' &= -\frac1{x^2}g'\\
y'' &= \frac2{x^3}g' + \frac1{x^4}g'' \tag 2\end{align}$$
to figure out what the differential equation $g$ satisfies, we  sub $(2)$ in the equation $$x^4y'' + x^3y' + y = 0. $$ that gives 
$$\begin{align}0 &=x^4\left( \frac2{x^3}g' + \frac1{x^4}g''\right) 
+x^3\left( -\frac1{x^2}g'\right)+g\\
&=g''+xg'+g\end{align}$$

with all explicit dependence you get either $$g''(1/x)+xg'(1/x) + g(1/x) = 0 $$ or $$xg''(x) + g'(x) + xg(x) = 0$$  the last equation is the bessels equations $J_0$ of order zero.

finally, we have  $$g(x) = J_0(x), y(x) = J_0(1/x). $$

Comment: This algorithm of substituting makes so much sense. Thanks.

Comment: @grdgfgr, you are welcome. i can remember how confusing it was for me at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^4\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}+x^3\frac{dy(x)}{dx}+y(x)=0$$

you can write it as

$$x^4\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy(x)}{dx}\right)+x^3\frac{dy(x)}{dx}+y(x)=0$$

Now you should be replacing both the $dx$ individually , note that it's a general confusion caused by notation. But $dx^2\neq d(dx)$ , so you can not differentiate $dx$ twice and put it back there, it won't work like that.

Rather here's the correct approach. Replacing all $dx$ individually.

$$x^4(-t^2)\frac{d}{dt}\left((-t^2)\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\right)+x^3*(-t^2)\frac{dy(t)}{dt}+y(t)=0$$

Which can be written as :

$$x^4*t^4\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2}+2*x^4*t^3\frac{dy(t)}{dt}-x^3*t^2\frac{dy}{dt}+y(t)=0$$

$$\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2}+\overbrace{2*\frac{1}{t}\frac{dy(t)}{dt}}-\frac{1}{t}\frac{dy}{dt}+y(t)=0$$

And here's your extra term. Also not that I did not write $y(t)$ as $y\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$ because both of them in the end represent the function dependency of $t$. It's just a matter of notation.

I may assume here you may have the follow two confusion for which I will Consider a random function let's say $y(t)=\frac{1}{1+t}$.

1) Why the both notations are equivalent?

$y(1/t)=\frac{t}{1+t}$ , now as you can see this is just another function in terms of $t$ so you can say let us say $g(t)=\frac{t}{1+t}$ but then again it's just a matter of choosing our alphabets we can even choose $f$ instead of $g$.

so $f(t)$ notation is equivalent to $f(\frac{1}{t})$ ,please note that i am **not saying both functions are equivalent**.

2) Why do not we apply chain rule for $y(\frac{1}{t})$?

Well if we were to find it's derivative with respect to t, chain rule would imply this statement

$\frac{dy(\frac{1}{t})}{d(\frac{1}{t})}*\frac{d(\frac{1}{t})}{dt}$ But the problem is that you do not require the $y'(\frac{1}{t})$ which is $\frac{dy(\frac{1}{t})}{d(\frac{1}{t})}$ hence you do not need to apply chain rule and you only require $\frac{dy(\frac{1}{t})}{dt}$

Comment: Here is my problem, why did  you immediately write $y(t)$. When you insert $1/t$ into $x$ you should have gotten $y(\frac1t)$

Comment: Let me add @grdgfgr 5 minute :)

Comment: @grdgfgr edited .